# Pandas Removing Roman Numerals from a 'Year' Column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a year column that contains roman numerals before the year from an IMDB Movie List I scraped. I tried using this code but it didn't remove them. The column name is called "Release Year". Any suggestions or insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe from the csv file and read the file into our dataFrame
df = pd.read_excel('Master IMDB File Practice Clean.xlsx')

# to remove roman numerals from column "Release Year"
df['Release Year'].str.replace(r'\W',"")
print(df)
```

This is the excel file with the highlighted roman numerals sprinkled throughout the column

[image]

Comment: Is that exactly how you're calling `str.replace`? Because `str.replace` is not an in place operation. You will need to assign back to update the DataFrame. `df['Release Year'] = df['Release Year'].str.replace(r'\W',"")`

Comment: Do you mean remove all non-digit characters:`df['Release Year'].str.replace(r'\D',"")`?

Comment: I changed it to what you suggested but it returned the same output with the roman numerals coming before the year. 

df['Release Year'] = df['Release Year'].str.replace(r'\W',"")
print(df)

Comment: QH, thanks! This code worked perfectly.

df['Release Year'] = df['Release Year'].str.replace(r'\D',"")
print(df)